# Hive NR map progress inconsistent and regurlarly restart from 0%

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have a Yarn MR (with two ec2 instances to mapreduce) job on a dataset of approximately a thousand avro records, and the map phase is behaving erratically. See the progress below. 
Of course i checked the logs on resourcemanager and nodemanagers and saw nothing suspicious, but these logs are too verbose

What is going on there ?

```
        hive> select * from nikon where qs_cs_s_aid='VIEW' limit 10;

        Total MapReduce jobs = 1
        Launching Job 1 out of 1
        Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
        Starting Job = job_1352281315350_0020, Tracking URL = http://blabla.ec2.internal:8088/proxy/application_1352281315350_0020/
        Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=blabla.com:8032 -kill job_1352281315350_0020
        Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 4; number of reducers: 0

        2012-11-07 11:14:40,976 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
        2012-11-07 11:15:06,136 Stage-1 map = 1%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 10.38 sec
        2012-11-07 11:15:07,253 Stage-1 map = 1%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 12.18 sec
        2012-11-07 11:15:08,371 Stage-1 map = 1%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 12.18 sec
        2012-11-07 11:15:09,491 Stage-1 map = 1%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 12.18 sec
        2012-11-07 11:15:10,643 Stage-1 map = 2%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 15.42 sec
        (...)
        2012-11-07 11:15:35,441 Stage-1 map = 28%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 37.77 sec
        2012-11-07 11:15:36,486 Stage-1 map = 28%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 37.77 sec

here restart at 16% ?

        2012-11-07 11:15:37,692 Stage-1 map = 16%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 21.15 sec
        2012-11-07 11:15:38,815 Stage-1 map = 16%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 21.15 sec
        2012-11-07 11:15:39,865 Stage-1 map = 16%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 21.15 sec
        2012-11-07 11:15:41,064 Stage-1 map = 18%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 22.4 sec
        2012-11-07 11:15:42,181 Stage-1 map = 18%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 22.4 sec
        2012-11-07 11:15:43,299 Stage-1 map = 18%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 22.4 sec

here restart at 0% ?

        2012-11-07 11:15:44,418 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
        2012-11-07 11:16:02,076 Stage-1 map = 1%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 6.86 sec
        2012-11-07 11:16:03,193 Stage-1 map = 1%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 6.86 sec
        2012-11-07 11:16:04,259 Stage-1 map = 2%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 8.45 sec
        (...)
        2012-11-07 11:16:31,291 Stage-1 map = 22%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.34 sec
        2012-11-07 11:16:32,414 Stage-1 map = 26%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 37.93 sec

here restart at 11% ?

        2012-11-07 11:16:33,459 Stage-1 map = 11%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 19.53 sec
        2012-11-07 11:16:34,507 Stage-1 map = 11%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 19.53 sec
        2012-11-07 11:16:35,731 Stage-1 map = 13%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 21.47 sec
        (...)
        2012-11-07 11:16:46,839 Stage-1 map = 17%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 24.14 sec

here restart at 0% ?

        2012-11-07 11:16:47,939 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
        2012-11-07 11:16:56,653 Stage-1 map = 1%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 7.54 sec
        2012-11-07 11:16:57,814 Stage-1 map = 1%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 7.54 sec
        (...)
```

Needless to say the job crashes after some time with an Error: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -56

Comment: Can you also share your create table statement please?

Answer (score 1):

This just looks like hadoop retrying the map tasks on failure (by default it retries them 3 times, each on a different host), which is how it makes your jobs more fault tolerant.

This is useful if the failures are caused by temporary issues on specific hosts (this happens more than you'd think). However in your case, you genuinely have an array out of bounds exception caused by something in your hive query. I'd check the failed task logs to try and debug why.